# Producer posts to topic and consumer subscribes to virtual topic

Tags: activemq-classic

We have a weird issue.

There are two equivalent topics: `topicA` and `topicB`.
The topics are created dynamically. Consumers subscribe to `VirtualTopic.topicA` and `VirtualTopic.topicB` correspondingly.

Consumers get the messages. We see equal number of arrived and dequeued messages in each virtual topic.

However, `topicA` says it has active subscribers, whereas `topicB` does not. All messages in `topicA` are dequeued. `topicB` shows the same number of messages as `VirtualTopic.topicB` contains, but none of the message is dequeued in `topicB`.

It looks like ActiveMQ just silently copies messages from regular to virtual topic. But it is not clear why it does it only for one of the topics.

Code which subscribes consumers is the same. Code that produces messages is the same. Configuration differs only in name of topics.

Can anyone give a hint what can define that difference in behaviour?

Comment: Need to provide code and output on what is happening as your question is very unclear.

Comment: Producer sends message to topic `policy.events'. Consumer is subscribed to virtual destination `queue://Consumer.PermissionsService.VirtualTopic.policy.events`. (shareable virtual topic). Number of enqueued messages increases for `policy.events` topic, number of dequeued messages stays zero. Consumer gets the messages, acknowledges them, number of enqueued and dequeued messages is equal for consumer queue.