# When using virtual topics should producer send to regular or virtual topic?

Tags: activemq-classic

Now we post to regular topic and able to consume messages from virtual topic. Is is a legit way?

Unfortunately, the correctness of this approach is not clear from the [docs](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html).

However, we notice some [odd behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265279/producer-posts-to-topic-and-consumer-subscribes-to-virtual-topic).

If it's ok, then we'd like to use it as it is now. Otherwise wee need to change topic names in all queues, ensured before there are no pending messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer in the book [Active MQ in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/activemq-in-action):

> Some naming conventions are required to allow virtual topics to
>   operate correctly. First, to identify that a topic is to be treated as
>   a virtual topic, the topic name should always follow the pattern of
>   `VirtualTopic.<topic name>`. So if you want to create a virtual topic
>   for a topic whose name is orders, you need to create a destination
>   with the name `VirtualTopic.orders`. This means that a publisher sends
>   messages to a topic named `VirtualTopic.orders`. In order to consume
>   from the queue that’s backed by the virtual topic, consumers must
>   subscribe to a queue whose name follows the pattern 
>   `Consumer.<consumer name>.VirtualTopic.<virtual topic name>`.